# how to parse json to struct with field named "type"

Tags: json, go, go-fiber

i can't seem to get the following code working.
The commented lines are sample request bodies, they always come in an array and with a parameter called "type" if i try to parse them i always end up with:

```
error =  json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.Entry
```

unfortunately i can't change the request body itself and have to use it somehow.

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
       "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
       "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/logger"
       "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/compress"
       )

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Use(logger.New(logger.Config{
    Format: "[${ip}]:${port} ${status} - ${method} ${path} - ${reqHeaders}\n${body}\n",
    }))

    app.Use(compress.New(compress.Config{
    Level: compress.LevelBestSpeed, // 1
    }))


type Entry struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Device string `json:"device"`
    DateString string `json:"dateString"`
    Date string `json:"date"`
    Sgv string `json:"sgv"`
    Delta string `json:"delta"`
    Direction string `json:"direction"`
    Noise string `json:"noise"`
    Filtered string `json:"filtered"`
    Unfiltered string `json:"unfiltered"`
    Rssi string `json:"rssi"`
}


type Entries struct {
    Entries []Entry
    }


    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, World!")
    })
// [{"type":"sgv","device":"0EM48R5JQ","dateString":"2023-06-23T22:39:16.000+02:00","date":1687552756000,"sgv":127,"delta":-0.400,"direction":"Flat","noise":1,"filtered":127000,"unfiltered":127000,"rssi":100},{"type":"sgv","device":"0EM48R5JQ","dateString":"2023-06-23T22:40:15.000+02:00","date":1687552815000,"sgv":127,"delta":-0.400,"direction":"Flat","noise":1,"filtered":127000,"unfiltered":127000,"rssi":100}]

// [{"type":"sgv","device":"0EM48R5JQ","dateString":"2023-06-23T22:00:14.000+02:00","date":1687550414000,"sgv":131,"delta":-0.550,"direction":"Flat","noise":1,"filtered":131000,"unfiltered":131000,"rssi":100}]
    app.Post("/api/v1/entries", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    entry := new(Entry)

    if err := c.BodyParser(entry); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error = ",err)
        return c.SendStatus(500)
    }

    return c.SendStatus(200)
    })

    app.Post("/entries", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.SendString("OK")
    })

    app.Post("/devicestatus", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.SendString("OK")
    })

    app.Post("/treatments", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.SendString("OK")
    })

    app.Listen(":3001")
}
```

i just want to get an array of structs that i can loop to add to a influx db.

**EDIT:**
thanks for the tip, i changed it to:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/compress"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/logger"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Use(logger.New(logger.Config{
        Format: "[${ip}]:${port} ${status} - ${method} ${path} - ${reqHeaders}\n${body}\n",
    }))

    app.Use(compress.New(compress.Config{
        Level: compress.LevelBestSpeed, // 1
    }))

    type Entry struct {
        Type       string `json:"type"`
        Device     string `json:"device"`
        DateString string `json:"dateString"`
        Date       int64  `json:"date"` // Updated type to int64
        Sgv        int    `json:"sgv"`
        Delta      float64 `json:"delta"`
        Direction  string `json:"direction"`
        Noise      int    `json:"noise"`
        Filtered   int    `json:"filtered"`
        Unfiltered int    `json:"unfiltered"`
        Rssi       int    `json:"rssi"`
    }

    type Entries []Entry

    app.Post("/api/v1/entries", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        entries := new(Entries)
        if err := c.BodyParser(entries); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error:", err)
            return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
        }

        // Process the entries as needed
        for _, entry := range *entries {
            // Perform actions with each entry
            fmt.Println(entry)
        }

        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusOK)
    })

    app.Listen(":3001")
}
```

it works now.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with anything being named `type`. Your incoming JSON is an array, but you're trying to unmarshal it into something that isn't an array (slice).

Answer (score 0):

As @hobbs said, the problem is you are trying to unmarshal an array to an `Entry` type.

You need to unmarshal it in a `[]Entry` and your `Entry` type does not have the correct field types, you can use [this site](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to create the correct struct based on your json.

Using the standard `json` library would look like this.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var es []Entry
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), &es); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(es)
}

type Entry struct {
    Type       string    `json:"type"`
    Device     string    `json:"device"`
    DateString time.Time `json:"dateString"`
    Date       int64     `json:"date"`
    Sgv        int       `json:"sgv"`
    Delta      float64   `json:"delta"`
    Direction  string    `json:"direction"`
    Noise      int       `json:"noise"`
    Filtered   int       `json:"filtered"`
    Unfiltered int       `json:"unfiltered"`
    Rssi       int       `json:"rssi"`
}

const payload = `[{"type":"sgv","device":"0EM48R5JQ","dateString":"2023-06-23T22:39:16.000+02:00","date":1687552756000,"sgv":127,"delta":-0.400,"direction":"Flat","noise":1,"filtered":127000,"unfiltered":127000,"rssi":100},{"type":"sgv","device":"0EM48R5JQ","dateString":"2023-06-23T22:40:15.000+02:00","date":1687552815000,"sgv":127,"delta":-0.400,"direction":"Flat","noise":1,"filtered":127000,"unfiltered":127000,"rssi":100}]`
```